# Can I sync mongodb and indexeddb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexeddb

js app with mongoDB database on host mLab, is this possible to sync mongoDB database with indexedDB to add offline user experience? In mongoDB i have objects like geolocation, and photos with hosting routes.